# Perform Action on DLL Unload/Close

Tags: .net, module

I'm writing a DLL for my .Net project that will handle some database interaction. I have things set up right now to continually reuse the same connection to the database (a UniData database) to keep my licensing under control. The DLL has a variable that holds the session and will open it if it is empty or close.

I would like to have the connection close automatically once the program closes. I've implemented my DLL as a module. I'm not sure how I would cause the module to perform the CloseSession operation when the program is closing. I know eventually sessions will timeout, but I'm trying to avoid that scenario.

Comment: The dbase engine is obscure, but are you sure this doesn't already happen?  Any decent .NET connection class wrapper will have a finalizer that shuts down the connection automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the [`AppDomain.ProcessExit` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.processexit.aspx) and beware of the behavior with multiple AppDomains.

Comment: Where could I get research to find out about the behavior of multiple AppDomains? I've never heard of such a thing.

Comment: Read the documentation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.processexit.aspx